# How to playback sound simultaneously after recording Java

Tags: java, audio, real-time

I am a newbie in programming and I want to learn more.

I want to record sound from my microphone in real-time. Below is my code for recording.

```
while (true) {
    int numBytesRead =  line.read(data, 0, data.length);
    out.write(data, 0, numBytesRead);
}
```

I tried to enter some codes there and I got to play some chunks of data but after a few seconds, the recording delays for about 3 seconds. Also, when I tried to talk, it plays backs in loop what I tried to say

```
while (true) {

    int numBytesRead =  line.read(data, 0, data.length);
    out.write(data, 0, numBytesRead);
    try {
        byte audio[] = out.toByteArray();
        InputStream input = new ByteArrayInputStream(audio);
        final SourceDataLine line1 = (SourceDataLine) AudioSystem.getLine(info1);
        final AudioInputStream ais = new AudioInputStream(input, format, audio.length / format.getFrameSize());
        int bufferSize = (int) format.getSampleRate() * format.getFrameSize();
        line1.open(format);
        line1.start();
        byte buffer[] = new byte[bufferSize];
        try {
            while (true) {
                numBytesRead = ais.read(buffer, 0, buffer.length);
                if (numBytesRead == -1) break;
                line1.write(buffer, 0, numBytesRead);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println("I/O problems: " + e);
            System.exit(-3);
        }
    }
```

Could somebody help me with my project.

Answer (score 1):

thank you for your answer sir. but i tried adding this line to my code and the playback worked

```
while (numBytesRemaining>0){
  numBytesRemaining-=line1.write(data,0,numBytesRemaining);
               }
```

thank you for your help sir

Answer (score 0):

why don't you use Clip for reading the recorded sound.

```
wavdata = out.toByteArray();
AudioInputStream ais = new AudioInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(wavdata), WAVFormat(), wavdata.length / WAVFormat().getFrameSize());
format = ais.getFormat();
info = new DataLine.Info(Clip.class, format);
Clip clip = (Clip) AudioSystem.getLine(info);
clip.open(ais);
//this is for playing
clip.start();
//this is for stopping or pause use it on the pause or stop button.
//clip.stop();
```

and this is the WAVFormat()

```
private AudioFormat WAVFormat() {

    int channels = 2;
    Encoding encoding = AudioFormat.Encoding.PCM_SIGNED;
    float sampleRate = rateconstant;
    int frameSize = framesize;
    float frameRate = rateconstant;
    int sampleSizeInBits = 16;
    boolean bigEndian = false;

    return new AudioFormat(encoding, sampleRate, sampleSizeInBits, channels, frameSize, frameRate, bigEndian);

}
```

hope it helps